# Use of innerHTML in javascript form

Tags: javascript

I see in this example how I can change the id contents with an input button and it works fine:

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText(){
    document.getElementById('boldStuff').innerHTML = 'Fred Flinstone';
}
</script>
<p>Welcome to the site <b id='boldStuff'>dude</b> </p> 
<input type='button' onclick='changeText()' value='Change Text'/>
```

When I try to use this to update a select or checkbox it does not work?  What can I use to achieve this result with a form element?

Non-Working Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText(){
    document.getElementById('boldStuff').innerHTML = '2';
}
</script>
<p>Welcome to the site 
<input type="checkbox" id="boldStuff" value="1" /></p> 
<input type='button' onclick='changeText()' value='Change'/>
```

Comment: Are you trying to change the checkbox from unchecked to checked by clicking the button, or just change the checkbox's value?

Comment: As everyone has mentioned, there is no `innerHTML` for an `input` tag, as it is an empty tag, like `br`, `hr`, `img`, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the element's `checked`, not its `innerHtml`. Setting the `innerHtml` is equivalent to doing:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="boldStuff" value="1">2</input>
```

which is invalid HTML.

If you want to set the checkbox to checked, do this:

```
document.getElementById('boldStuff').checked = true;
```

Comment: I was thinking this as well, but I am guessing OP wants to change the value submitted or the words next to the checkbox.

Comment: Ah, okay. Little bit difficult to understand. In that case, either of the other answers should help him.

Comment: That was my fault...I did need .checked = true;

Comment: @ColinDeClue how do I handle a form select?  This does not seem to work? document.getElementById('Skill_1').option = 20;

Comment: For a select element, you can set the selected index: `document.getElementById('Skill_1').selectedIndex = 2;`

Answer (score 3):

`innerHTML` change the HTML between the opening and closing tag. Since the input tag is a self closing tag (tag that end with `/>`, even though it is valid in HTML5 to leave the `/` behind), there is no `innerHTML`.

If you want to change the value, just target the `value` property :

```
document.getElementById('boldStuff').value = '2';
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set the value, *set the value* (and not innerHTML):

```
document.getElementById('boldStuff').value = '2';
```

Most attributes can be found in this way, tho some must be gotten from [`element.getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute) and set with [`element.setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute).

Answer (score 0):

to make changes via innerHTML you first need to have a innerHTML value to change

so

```
document.getElementById('***').innerHTML="2";
```

the corresponding HTML would need to look similar to this:

```
<p id="***">some text</p>
```